# How do I render all actors in a single area using DirectX 11 in C++ efficiently and easily?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-11, direct3d

I have searched SO and have not found one relating to the very basics, explaining step by step. We are in need of this.

Assuming that I am using only the [DirectX SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) supplied by microsoft.

Also assuming that I have `.fbx` and `.3ds` models already made and in the working directory which are generic, monochrome, shapes (cube, sphere, pyramid, etc.).

Please also condense the rendering process into a function that uses the directX functions (As in, can be compiled), as an example:

```
//the following is a suggestion, not a guideline for those who
//want to get into 3D programming. 
vector<DX3DModel>modelsToBeRendered;
void bufferFrame(vector<DX3DModel>models){
    while(1){
    /* something something vertexes, lets say DX3DModel only contains vertexes
    and a string as a file link
    (Rendering code would make it very
    messy in the question, but please include it in the answer.) */

       //render models.end(); here

        models.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Using a method similar to what I have above, how would I (safely) render all other actors in a single "area" while still being able to manipulate vertexes at will?

(Area is a (AxBx1) model which we will call `field.fbx`. This is a boundary for all actors to exist on)

Comment: If you would like to add anything (or have me clarify) , please do. This question is meant to help others.

Comment: You'd have to load the models' meshes in to vertex buffers, and the models' textures into texture resources. You'd need to load a vertex shader that transforms, skins (animates) and maybe lights the mesh's vertices, and a pixel shader that applies the texture and maybe lights the pixels. Then for each model, set its vertex buffer and texture, set a transformation to position the model along with the transformations needed for the skinning and then draw the model. Plus a whole bunch of details I left out because this question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Direct3D 11 API, much like the OpenGL API, is a low-level rendering API that works in terms of resources and drawing operations on constructs containing points, lines, and triangles. It's not a high-level API that can directly load or render an model file from a 3D editor, nor does it inherently have a material/effects system.

If you are new to DirectX 11, you should consider using the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) as a good starting-point. You can't directly render from a `3DS` or `FBX` model, but you can use either the built-in Visual Studio content pipeline for converting to a `CMO` or use the [Samples Content Exporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter) to convert to `SDKMESH`, both of which can be loaded by *DirectX Tool Kit*.

Using the *DirectX Tool Kit*, you'd be able to use the `Model` class and get something basically like what you propose. See the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started), particularly the lesson [Rendering a model](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model).

> For Direct3D 11 development, you should strongly consider *not* using the legacy DirectX SDK as it's deprecated. If you are using VS 2012 or later, you don't need it. See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/).